# SublimeRope Autocompletions not working on Windows

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimerope

I'm having trouble getting autocompletions to work for SublimeRope on Windows 8.

First, I noticed that SublimeRope messes up paths when creating a new Rope project on Windows, so I fixed the `python_path` prefs in .ropeproject > config.py, which are:

```
prefs.add('python_path', 'C:/Users/brandon/python_virtualenvs/aa/Lib/site-packages')
prefs.add('python_path', 'C:/Users/brandon/django_projects/andrews-app')
```

I've also tried specifying the packages to auto-import in my project file:

```
"rope_autoimport_modules": ["django.*"]
```

When I attempt to run: `Rope: Regenerate Global Module Cache`, I get an error:

`"Missing modules in configuration file"`

which Google has not been able to provide an answer for. Is anyone on Windows able to get SublimeRope working? I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

I documented how I kind of fixed it here:

https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope/issues/54

Basically, I added:

sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages")

in sublime_rope.py itself.

Obviously a hack, but it works until the code gets fixed upstream.

Comment: Hmm. That would be fine if I were only dealing with the system Python, however, I have lots of VirtualEnvs for which I would have to alter the path each time, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You can probably edit virtualenv to automatically edit sublime_rope.py but it's incredibly messy and I don't suggest doing it.  Honestly, until it gets fixed upstream, this is just a very quick and dirty fix.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll avoid that and just continue to fire up my Linux VM, but thank you very much for taking the time to comment.